# Vite.js build: how to produce output index.html if my entry is named differently

Tags: javascript, vite, rollup

I have several entry points `app1.html`, `app2.html`,
when building i only need to build one at a time (by having multiple `vite{x}.config.ts` files)

how can i tell vite/rollup to output `index.html` (and not `app1.html`) in the `dist` folder

my current configuration looks like this:

```
...
return {
  build: {
    rollupOptions: {
      input: resolve(__dirname, 'app1.html'),
      output: // something needs to go here
    }
 }
}
```

no matter what i put into `output`, the `dist` foldare contains html file called exactly as my entry point, i need it to be `index.html`

to generalize: i want to be able to have multiple entry html files (and their respective vite config file) by building which should produce `dist` folder with its own `index.html`

Answer (score 1):

```
defineConfig({
    build: {
      rollupOptions: {
        input: {
          app: 'your_html_name.html',
        },
      },
    },
    plugins: [
      createHtmlPlugin({
        template: 'your_html_name.html',
      }),
      {
        name: "vite-postbuild",
        closeBundle: async () => {
          const buildDir = path.join(__dirname, "dist");
          const oldPath = path.join(buildDir, 'your_html_name.html');
          const newPath = path.join(buildDir, "index.html");

          await fs.rename(oldPath, newPath);
        },
      },
    ],
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

`output` should be an object with a `file` property

https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#configuration-files

```js
rollupOptions: {
  input: resolve(__dirname, 'app1.html'),
  output: {
    file: "index.html",
    //format: "html", // might need this
  }
}
```

Comment: unfortunately this didnt work, i get the following error: `Invalid value for option "output.dir" - you must set either "output.file" for a single-file build or "output.dir" when generating multiple chunks.
error during build:
Error: Invalid value for option "output.dir" - you must set either "output.file" for a single-file build or "output.dir" when generating multiple chunks.`